# Word for 'Bingo' without gambling assocations

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm building a web application for a client, however the gambling associations with the word 'Bingo' are something we would like to avoid.

The game functions similar to traditional Bingo, with a grid of options that may or may not happen during the game.

Ideally the word would start with a B for alliteration.

Any ideas?

Comment: When I think of Bingo, I think of seniors and irritating school assignments.  The stakes in Bingo aren't particularly high.

Comment: Bongi. You could just rearrange columns in bingo cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For game purposes, almost any exclamation could be used, including words that aren't normally exclamations... "Bravo!" is the best I can think of offhand.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **'Bazinga!'**. Might have too strong *Big Bang Theory* references though.

Answer (score 0):

*Basta!* (Italian for "Stop it! Enough!")

Comment: I don't think a gambling concern would encourage that attitude.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - The OP stated, "however the gambling associations with the word 'Bingo' are something we would like to *avoid*."

Answer (score 0):

*Boingo*. But no, boingo is already the name of a telecommunications company.

Betandgo (portmanteau of bet-and-go).

Ballegro (portmanteau of Latin balle (ball) and allegre (argue))

Balago (Go Brother, Bala = PNG/Australian slang for brother)